# al hacer split, obtengo el código ASCII y deseo el string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

Buen día,me encontré con el siguiente problema. supongamos que tengo esta cadena:

```
string cadena="1,2,3,4,5"
```

le aplico un método string.Split() y lo guardo en un array:

```
string[] partes=cadena.Split(',');
```

hago un foreach para asignar el valor del array:

```
foreach(var a in partes){
    int id=Convert.ToInt32(a);
}
```

en el caso de ejemplo, el primer elemento de la cadena es 1, al hacer debug de mi programa, veo que, el valor de a, en la primera iteración, es:

```
49'1'
```

y al momento de asignar el valor, guarda `49` y no `1`, como esperaría. veo que a es considerado como char, y `49` corresponde a su código ASCII. pensé en convertir de ASCII a string, pero no creo que sea la manera adecuada (¿qué haría en casos donde sea más de un dígito?)
en fin, no entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal, agradecería bastante si alguien podría echarme una mano :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer la conversión del tipo de dato de `String` a `int`, y cabe mencionar que en este caso tu variable `id` la estas creando en dentro del `loop` y solo la podrás usar allí:

```
using System;

public class Program
 {
    public static void Main()
 {
    int id=0;
    string cadena="1,2,3,4,5";
    string[] partes=cadena.Split(',');
    foreach(var a in partes){
         id=Convert.ToInt32(a);
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }

  }
}
```

Puedes ver la demostración [aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tOJLy3)

Comment: me faltó añadir eso en mi pregunta, de hecho hago un `Convert.ToInt32(a);` pero convierte el 49, no el 1

Comment: probé como lo tienes y sólo lleva una pequeña corrección, como a me lo devuelve como tipo char, hay que hacer una conversión a string antes del Int32.parse. quedaría: `Int32.Parse(a.ToString());`